# Internals of ncurses: console input

Tags: c, ansi-escape, console-input

How exactly does Ncurses capture input into the console? I would like to implement it myself instead of using ncurses due to the overhead that ncurses is causing.

Thanks!

Comment: ncurses is open source, the source is available for download and study.

Comment: Well i was more looking for a general direction on how it does it, I am crunched for time and do not have a long time to go sift through thousands of lines of code.

Comment: 2 hints : `ioctl` and `escape codes`. FYI - tracing `ncurses` will be faster. Source : I've done both

Comment: It puts the terminal in raw mode and then reads character by character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very short and basically: It  might use [the TTY `ioctl` calls](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty_ioctl.4.html) to get and set flags needed for the different modes. Then it could simply use [`read`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) to read characters in a blocking or non-blocking manner.

Special keys (like the function keys for example) are read using multiple characters which are parsed.